# Not able to display Text in ObjectViewList TreeView

Tags: c#, objectlistview, treelistview

I'm using the ObjectViewList TreeListView and I followed the example but I'm not getting the text to appear. The TreeListView does populate and you can see the nodes that can expand and they do expand with the correct number of children but the text doesn't display.

Below is the code:

```
private void SetupTree(TreeNode objectRoot)
    {

        
        this.treeObjectView.CanExpandGetter = delegate (object x) {
            return ((TreeNode)x).Nodes.Count > 0;
        };
       
        this.treeObjectView.ChildrenGetter = delegate (object x) {
            try
            {
                return ((TreeNode)x).Nodes;
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () {
                    this.treeObjectView.Collapse(x);
                    MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "ObjectListViewDemo", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                });
                return new ArrayList();
            }
        };
        
        ArrayList roots = new ArrayList();
        
        foreach (TreeNode di in objectRoot.Nodes)
        {
             roots.Add(di);                
        }           

        this.treeObjectView.Roots = roots;        
    }
```

And here is the Designer code:

```
    {

        // 
        // treeObjectView
        // 
        this.treeObjectView.AllColumns.Add(this.objectName);
        this.treeObjectView.CellEditUseWholeCell = false;
        this.treeObjectView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnHeader[] {
        this.objectName});
        this.treeObjectView.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.treeObjectView.HideSelection = false;
        this.treeObjectView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
        this.treeObjectView.Name = "treeObjectView";
        this.treeObjectView.ShowGroups = false;
        this.treeObjectView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(533, 589);
        this.treeObjectView.TabIndex = 3;
        this.treeObjectView.UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
        this.treeObjectView.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
        this.treeObjectView.VirtualMode = true;
        // 
        // objectName
        // 
        this.objectName.MinimumWidth = 200;
        this.objectName.Text = "Text";
        this.objectName.ToolTipText = "Object Name";
        this.objectName.Width = 200;
     }
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually brain dead stupid simple, I wasn't paying close attention to the demo. All you have to do is set the property that you want to display.

```
 this.objectName.AspectName = "Text";
```